# sshfs, linux - how to mount with read-only access

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, sshfs

I need to mount other server via sshfs with read-only mode. My OS is Linux (Ubuntu). Is it possible to do that?

My command used with that connection is:

```
sudo sshfs user@123.123.123.123:/home/user /media/mountpoint/ -o allow_other
```

After running that I have write-access. I need to have read-only. Please help.

Comment: Not a programming question, belongs to SuperUser or Unix&Linux

Answer (score 28, accepted):

just add one more option: `sshfs user@123.123.123.123:/home/user /media/mountpoint/ -o allow_other -o ro` .
this should help: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=975107

Comment: one can also chain the options with comma: `-o idmap=user,ro,allow_other`